# Is there an input type selector for a radiolist

Tags: css

I am trying to target a radiolist in css.  This is for a C# aspx web page and my CSS skills are in their infancy.  The problem I am having is that the `input[type=radio]` selector seems to partially work, but not fully.  For example, certain things I try act on just the radio buttons as opposed to the text for the radio buttons.  That I can get around, however I am trying to target a label after the radio button and not succeeding using 
`input[type=radio]:focus + .label-text` whereas I can target a different item using `input[type=text]:focus + .label-text`

This is the complete code.  Ive added a comment at the class in question.  There is some code behind to select which of the 3 items are in focus that I am not including for simplicity, but I think my problem is a simple CSS misunderstanding and Im hoping one of you will just see it instantly and I can smack my hand on my head:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server" >
<style>
input[type=text] {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -300%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -300%);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.25, 0.8, 0.3);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.25, 0.8, 0.3);

  display: block;
  width: 70vw;
  opacity: 0;

  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;

}

input[type=text]:focus {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.45, 0.1, 0.85) 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.45, 0.1, 0.85) 0.5s;
}

input[type=radio]:focus:before {

  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.5) translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: scale(.5) translate(-50%, -50%);
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.45, 0.1, 0.85) 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.45, 0.1, 0.85) 0.5s;  
}

input[type=radio] {

  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(2.0) translate(0%, 0%);
          transform: scale(2.0) translate(0%, 0%);
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out; 

  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  color: black;

}


input[type=radio]:focus {

  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: scale(2.0) translate(0%, 0%);
          transform: scale(2.0) translate(0%, 0%);
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out; 
}

/*+ .label-text also tried + #Label5 also label #Label5, also label .label-text, also tried .radiolist also tried all with ~*/
input[type=radio]:focus + .label-text {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.45, 0.1, 0.85) 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.45, 0.1, 0.85) 0.4s;
}

input[type=text]:focus + .label-text {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.45, 0.1, 0.85) 0.4s;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.45, 0.1, 0.85) 0.4s;
}


.label-text {
  position: fixed;
  top: calc(50% - 4rem);
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -200%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -200%);
  width: 70vw;
  padding: 3.125rem 0 1.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 18px; 
  -webkit-transition: all 1.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.25, 0.8, 0.3) .5s; 
  transition: all 1.7s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.25, 0.8, 0.3) .5s; 

}


 .radioList {
    margin-left:30%;
    margin-top:10%;
 }

  .radioList label {
      margin-left:15px;
      text-align:center;
 }

 </style>



<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="ButtonNext">


<asp:TextBox ID="questionNumTextBox" runat="server" visible="false" Text="-1"  ></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:TextBox ID="fullNameTextBox" runat="server"  placeholder="Full Name" ></asp:TextBox>     
    <asp:Label ID="Label1"  runat="server" Text="What is your Name?"  class="label-text" ></asp:Label> 



    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="sexRbl" runat="server"  RepeatDirection="Horizontal" class="radioList" >
        <asp:ListItem ID="MaleRB" runat="server"  Text="Male" Selected="True"  /><asp:ListItem ID="FemaleRB" runat="server"  Text="Female"   />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
     <asp:label id="Label5" runat="server" Text="What is your Gender?" class="label-text"></asp:label>


   <asp:TextBox ID="ageTextBox" runat="server" placeholder="Age?"  ></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:label id="Label7" runat="server" Text="What is your Age?"  class="label-text"></asp:label>
           </asp:Panel>


    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonNext" Text="Next »" class="btn btn-default" OnClick="ButtonNext_Click" Visible="true" />


</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Instead of :focus, try :checked which works better with radio inputs and checkboxes

Comment: Thank you for that, in this case the "focus" is driven in code so as the "focus" is forced to change, the element sails in or does something.  My problem though is not with the radio button specifically. . .I am trying to get to the Label right after it (+ .label-text). . .that is the piece that is not working and I THINK it is because the radio button (whether it is focused or checked) is a child to the radiolist.  That's why I am trying to find a way to target that parent radio list instead of the radio button.

Comment: I have been successful changing the radiobuttonlists to drop down lists.  There is also not an "input" selector css class that specifically works on drop down lists, but select{} does act on drop down lists ie 'input[type=text]:focus, select:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}' will work on similarly on the input types of text (ie textbox) and the selected item of the ddl.  Because the selected item is part of the same control with the rest of the drop down, it will travel move or appear as a group. . .radio button lists do not. . .so if anyone encounters a solution to this, I sure would love to learn.

Comment: Good to hear you've found an alternative for your problem, Lemme see if I can emulate what you are looking for with the radiobuttons

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I have reproduced with pure `HTML`, since I see yours is being loaded with `ASP`.
Based on this problem here:

```
.....
/*+ .label-text also tried + #Label5 also label #Label5, also label .label-text, also tried .radiolist also tried all with ~*/
input[type=radio]:focus + .label-text { .....
```

I tried with a somewhat similar format and the results are working as expected:

```css
label {
    opacity: 0.4;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

input[type=radio] {
    outline: none;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

input[type=radio]:focus {
    width: 20px;
    outline: 1px solid rgb(4, 111, 138);
}

input[type=radio]:focus + label {
    outline: 1px solid rgb(4, 111, 138);
    opacity: 1;
}
/* When you remove focus on the radio button, the label reverts to its original state */

/* input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    outline: 1px solid rgb(4, 111, 138);
    opacity: 1;
} */
/* For the one above, when you remove focus, the label remains as it is if the radio button will be checked */
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="value1" id="radio1"/>
    <label>Value 1</label>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="value2" id="radio2"/>
    <label>Value 2</label>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="radio" name="test" value="value3" id="radio3"/>
    <label>Value 3</label>
</div>
```

The results are as expected for the label -- Correct me if it's not so.
As for your code, maybe there is a difference in how asp handles labels ...